# EC2 instance running node not connecting over http

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I have a new EC2 instance. I created it a couple of days ago. I installed node on it and after that I am trying to check if the node server is able to listen to the incoming request. I started node server and am trying to access the EC2 instance over http but didn't get any success. I have checked the following
1) Server is running. I have started the node server and got the message that server is running on 8080
2) I have checked the security group of the instance and I have allowed all the inbound connection on the port 80 and 8080
3) I pinged EC2 public DNS and was able to get the response from it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your instance is in public subnet, since you have mentioned about public DNS, check if you have internet gateway configured or have an ElasticIP attached to the instance.

Comment: thanks for the input. I was not using elastic ip but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I tried accessing port 80 by installing apache server and it worked. When I am trying to access any custom tcp port, then I am not able to access the site.

Comment: Seems to be some problem with my Anti virus. My machine is able to connect to port 80 of EC2 instance but not the 8080 port. I tried changing my configuration but was not able to get any result.

Comment: Did you check your server firewalls, NACLs etc in case 8080 is blocked anywhere on your IP range? Also, check node server configuration if it's listening on 8080 correctly or not.